# Thrown expression type 'Error?' does not conform to 'Error' swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode8

Changing my playground code to Swift 3, Xcode suggested changing

```
if let requestError = error {
    completion({throw (Error(code: requestError._code, description: requestError.localizedDescription, innerError: nil, informations:nil))})
}
```

to

```
if let requestError = error {
    completion({throw (Error(code: requestError._code, description: requestError.localizedDescription, innerError: nil, informations:nil)) as! Error})
}
```

But I get this error: 
 "'Error' is not convertible to 'Error'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?"

Comment: How is your error type defined?

Answer (score 5):

Error handling in Swift 3 is different. Error is now a protocol that you conform to, so you define your error cases and then throw.

```
enum NetworkError: Error {
    case unauthorised
    case timeout
    case serverError
    case invalidResponse
}

guard let httpUrlResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
   throw NetworkError.invalidResponse
}
```

For more information please see the [Official Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html)